# Does $y'y= \hat y' y + e'e$ hold for the least square model?

Tags: regression, self-study, mathematical-statistics, proof

I want to show that $y'y= \hat y' \hat y + e'e$ hold for the least square model. I found out that:

$\hat y= X b$ with  $b$ the least squares estimator of the coefficient vector and $e$ the residual vector.

I really appreciate your hints!

Comment: Are you sure about equality of the dimension of $y'y$ and $\hat{y}y'$?

Comment: The second term in your question cannot be correct; think carefully about @vinux 's question

Comment: @vinux thx you very much for your answer! However, I changed my equation to $$y'y= \hat y' \hat y + e'e$ $. I hope its now right

Comment: @Glen_b Thx for your answer! Pls see my comment above

Comment: I took the liberty of similarly correcting your title.

Comment: Do you know anything about the value of $\hat{y}'e$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $X$ is a full rank matrix. $y= \hat{y}+e$

\begin{align*}
y'y &= (\hat{y}+e)'(\hat{y}+e) \\
    &=  \hat{y}'\hat{y}+ e'e + e'\hat{y} + \hat{y}'e  \\
e'\hat{y} &= \hat{y}'e= b'X'e \\
          &= b'*\textbf{0} = 0   
\end{align*}

X'e=0 is the normal equation in the least square estimation.

Hence proved.

Note: Normal equation is

$X'y -X'Xb=\textbf{0} \Rightarrow X'(y-Xb)=X'e=\textbf{0}$) 
See this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_involving_ordinary_least_squares) for more info.